# How to create a non-perpendicular near clipping plane in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, shader

I have a need for setting up clipping planes that aren't perpendicular to the camera. Doing that for the far plane was easy: I just added a shader that clears the background.

I just can't figure out how to do the same for the near clipping plane. I've tried to think of solutions dealing with multiple shaders and planes, a special cutting shader, having multiple cameras for this or somehow storing the view as a texture, but those ideas are mostly imperfect even if they were implementable. What I basically need is a shader that would say "don't render anything that's in front of me". Is that possible? Can I eg. make a shader to make the passed pixels "final"?

Comment: I don't have a proper answer as I don't master this kind of thing, but if you used a shader for the far plane can't you do the same for the near plane ? discard vertex that are on the camera side of the cutting plane.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. But I don't think that works. 

I can't do the same for the near plane as I do for the far plane. With the back plane the plane naturally comes on top of what's behind it so I can just clear whatever was written there beforehand. With the near plane things go in front of it, so I should somehow prevent them from being rendered (or have them somehow drawn "behind" the curtain of the near plane).

What you're suggesting would probably work if I could add a shader for all items that are in front of the near plane. But I can't as they need to have their own shaders.

Comment: I'm thinking you could do it on the software end, for exemple every 10 frames or so you find all objects that are behind the front curtain and deactivate their mesh renderer component. Then for the objects that are on the curtain you could find a way to cut them according to the plane.

Comment: Thanks for the comment again. Yeah, I know that is an option and that is a plan B currently. In fact I'll actually need to do some of that cutting in any case, but if I could find a more simple way of doing the front clipping, I could get away with doing a lot less of that cutting. This would mean not only more simple implementation, but saving computation power.

Comment: Oh boy, as of Unity5 the farplane clipping isn't working properly any more either! I had a shader which simply did Blend Zero One, and it worked in Unity4, but in Unity5 it lets stuff through when looking from certain angles/distances. :(